# Python Module name conflict while learning Wagtail

Tags: python, wagtail, python-venv

I am following the tutorial here:
http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/getting_started/tutorial.html

When I execute:

```
$ wagtail start mysite mysite
```

I get:

```
'mysite' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as a project name. Please try another name
```

How do  I proceed?

Comment: Why `wagtail start mysite mysite`? Should read `wagtail start mysite` one mysite

Comment: Ah, I see, that is confusing. The instructions create the site inside a folder with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to look at here is: what package is `mysite`, and then *where* is it?

If you take a look on PyPi.org (where python packages are hosted) there isn't one called mysite ([this page 404s](https://pypi.org/project/mysite/)).

There's no third party package in pypi called `mysite`, so then you have to look locally. You probably have a folder on your computer called `mysite` in the virtual environment you're in.

> Try changing directories and re-run `wagtail start mysite`

**Note**: If you run `wagtail start mysite mysite` without a directory called `mysite` you might run into an error that says *"Destination directory '/path/to/folder/mysite' does not exist, please create it first."*

Fun trick: if you run into this error again in the future you can see all of your currently installed pypi packages by typing `pip freeze`. You can also filter through them with `pip freeze | grep packagename`.

Hope this helps!